# How do I reconnect to the same Asteroid instance on a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, meteor, google-chrome-extension, ddp

I am using the library mondora/[asteroid](https://github.com/mondora/asteroid) in order to build a Chrome extension while using a Meteor backend.  I am having an issue storing and carrying over the asteroid instance from the background page or when I open or close the popup.  I need to keep track of if the user is logged in or  not.

To create the asteroid instance, I use:

```
const Asteroid = createClass();
asteroid = new Asteroid({
  endpoint: 'ws://localhost:3000/
});
```

I have tried passing the asteroid instance through chrome.storage.local.set, but when I try to use it with chrome.storage.local.get, I get an error that doesn't allow me to use asteroid functions.

What is the best way to communicate back and forth to the users?

Comment: Messaging is only for simple JSON-ifiable objects so you'll have to work with an instance inside one context.

Comment: Oh ok.  Do you have any suggestions as to how I can log someone in on each instance?  I know I can transfer their userId, but how can I log them in with just that

Comment: all your communication with backend must happen in background, not popup.

Comment: oh.  So how do I communicate between the popup and the background?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [older version](https://github.com/mondora/asteroid/tree/0.7.0) which have internal mechanism to work with chrome extensions api. It stores user and you can restore user session in background scope with `resumeLoginPromise`

```
asteroid.resumeLoginPromise.then((userId) => {
     //do something with user
    }).catch(function(ex) {
      console.error(ex);
      // No login token
    });
  }
});
```

In repo you can find special [build for chrome](https://github.com/mondora/asteroid/blob/0.7.0/dist/asteroid.chrome.js)